# Near location for aws server setup for gulf countries

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I setting up an AWS server for gulf countries and it is showing a few options for choosing near locations.  So I want to know the nearest  country location.

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/17sa_0OwEE8-yrgdzlmW1uwP403CQyaIf/view   please check all showing country name from here.

Comment: A list of AWS Regions can be found at: [Global Infrastructure](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/global-infrastructure/)

Answer (score 0):

Update : With the opening of `me-south-1` in **Bahrain**, it is the natural choice for workloads in the Gulf States.

---

`AWS Mumbai(ap-south-1)` would likely be the closest geographically. `Frankfurt (eu-central-1)` would probably be the second closest.

You can test speeds and latencies to various cloud regions/services with these tools:

[speedtest](https://cloudharmony.com/speedtest)

[cloud ping](https://www.cloudping.info/)